# Pass PHP variable on OnClick method

Tags: javascript

I already tried all the methods i saw here in Stackoverflow but im getting errors.

Im trying to pass a php variable value to a javascript function, im trying to do both methods:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete('.$contact['idContact'].')"> Delete </a></td>';
```

This method above thinks the value of the idContact is actually a variable, so he is trying to get the value of the variable "105" (the value of idContact)

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete("'.$contact['idContact'].'")"> Delete </a></td>';
```

This method gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

What is the correct way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Here is a simple code to show my problem:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

function eliminate(test)
{
    alert(test);
}

</script>
</head>

<?

$test = "name";

echo '<a href="#" onclick="eliminate('.$test.')"> Delete </a>';

?>

</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your first method? I'm not understanding.

Comment: Mixing *three languages* on *one line of code* is just begging for syntax problems.

Comment: the first method thinks the value of my variable is in fact a variable.

Comment: I know theere isnt a } in my code but if i remove my variable it works. If i do `onclick=delete()` i dont get any error so the error is in this line.

Comment: I believe "delete" is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in JavaScript. Try renaming your function to something else, like "deleteEntry". [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ohyf76u6/).

Comment: Regarding your edit, the [answer from @PoopBagelResurrected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130859/pass-php-variable-on-onclick-method#answer-38130923) answers your question about escaping quotes.

Comment: just tested. You are 100% right. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gotta quote it if it's a string or else js will assume it's a variable

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete(\''.$contact['idContact'].'\')"> Delete </a></td>';
```

note the escaped quotes on either side `\'`

a better way of passing variable from php to js is to json encode them, that will take care of quotes and things...

Comment: i tried to `$test = json_encode($contact['idContact']);` and then `echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete('.$test.')"> Delete </a></td>';` but still give me error.

Comment: Even `echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete('.json_encode($contact['idContact']).')"> Delete </a></td>';`
 give me error.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: several of your examples look like they would work since (i assume) it's an id number not a string.. the error is most likely from somewhere else..

Comment: yea, you've got a `}` spmewhere where it doesn't belong.. this could just mean that you forgot a semicolon at the end of a line somewheree.. php expected a semicolon and got a curly instead.

Comment: If i do `onclick="delete()"` my code works so the error must be while passing a variable.

Comment: php doesn't lie :P you've got an error... maybe it's not being shown in the ui, but if it's there it's there. please make a pastebin with the full code and let us have a look at the whole thing.. thing is, php should give you the exact line number for that eerror

Comment: Yeah you are right. Since the code did work without the variable i though it was the way i was doing that was wrong but i did a small script and it worked. Thanks Bagel. I think i was too stubborn to see it.

Comment: Ok i got one error fixed but this way: `echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="delete('.$contact['idContact'].')"> Delete </a></td>';` does not accept string or char. If i pass a int its ok but if i pass a string i get `drasirlene is not defined` and in this case `drasirlene` is the name of the person. How can i pass a string? I know i need single quotes but how can i add those?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function eliminate(test){
     alert(test);
   }
<script>
</head>
<body>
<?php $test="name"; ?>
<a href="" onclick="eliminate('<?php echo $test; ?>')">delete</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid confusion use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for this

```
$button=<<<HTML
<a href="#" onclick="eliminate('$test')"> Delete </a>
HTML;
echo $button
```

Also remeber if you are using json as paramter make sure to escape them properly or it will not work